# How can I access @user or user from a mailer using Devise and Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

```
class JobMailer < ActionMailer::Base

default :from => "emailer@email.com"

def new_job_email_for_client
#
#
@url = "http://simplesite.com/users/login"
mail(:to => @???,
      :subject => "You have created a new case on simplesite.")
end

end
```

I would like each user to receive an email each and every time he/she creates a "job." In other parts of the application, I can access @user and user.email and such, but in the mailer I'm getting "undefined errors."

How can I access the current users email address in the mailer (taking into consideration that Devise is in control of Users)?

Comment: Are you running the JobMailer in the background or is it run during the user's web request?

Comment: It's run during the user's web request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a great way of doing it, but this is how I got it working:

```
def new_job_email_for_client(user_email)
@url = "http://simplesite.com/users/login"
mail(:to => user_email,
      :subject => "You have created a new case.")
end
```